# Ag Grid aggregation function with Valuegetter

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

In AgGrid, I am tyring to use aggregation functions and valuegetter on the same column. It seems that because of valuegetter, my aggreation functions are not working, I just get 0 or null value on aggregation. Could you please check my code for any possible solutions?
Thanks.

```
{ headerName: "Price", filter: "agNumberColumnFilter", valueGetter: priceValueGetter, allowedAggFuncs: ['avg', 'sum', 'min', 'max']};


function priceValueGetter(params) {
    var value = '';

    if (params.data) {
        var EPrice = params.data.a;
        var p1 = params.data.b;
        if (EPrice && p1) {
            value = (EPrice - p1).toFixed(2);
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your valueGetter is returning a string.
So the built-in aggregation functions, which expect numbers, are failing.

Try this valueGetter instead:

```
function priceValueGetter(params): number {
    if (params.data && params.data.a && params.data.b) {
        return params.data.a - params.data.b
    }
    return null;
}
```

This won't format the way that you want, but you can fix that by adding a valueFormatter.

One other piece of advice - given that you have a variable named 'EPrice', I'm assuming that you're dealing with money. You shouldn't depend on Javascript's native 'number' type for money, as it is essentially a 'float', and rounding errors will ensue. There are lots of articles about how to properly handle monetary values in Javascript - I personally use a Javascript port of Java's BigDecimal class, called ['big.js'](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js), but there are several other solutions.

Edit - also be careful of using `if` on a `number` - it evaluates to `false` if the number is zero. If that's what you want, fine, but if it isn't, adjust your logic accordingly.